# Magento 1.9 POA displaying in cart but not at Order Review / Invoices

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a Magento 1.9 website where some products use POA rather than a price. By default Magento requires a price for every product so I have set 0.00 and then selected POA from the dropdown under the price field.

On the frontend of the site and in the cart POA is displayed rather than 0.00. However at Order Review / Invoices / Emails 0.00 is displayed.

Any advice on how to display POA rather than 0.00 would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you create POA attribute using admin?

Comment: Yes, the POA attribute has been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

After the line:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

Add this line:

```
if ($_product->getAttributeText(‘poa’)==NULL):
```

Now go to the end of the file and add:

getAttributeText(‘poa’) ?>

Fix listing pages
Remove add to cart buttons from listing pages, open: /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

There are two instances of this line, one for grid and one for list:

```
<button type=”button” title=”<?php echo $this->__(‘Add to Cart’) ?>” class=”button btn-cart” onclick=”setLocation(‘<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>’)”><span><span><?php echo $this->__(‘Add to Cart’) ?></span></span></button>
```

Add an if around them so that that they look like:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText(‘poa’)==NULL): ?>
<button class=”button” onclick=”setLocation(‘<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>’)”><span><?php echo $this->__(‘Add to Cart’) ?></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My client would still like to the customer to check out with the product price as 0.00 (they will then contact the customer to discuss the order - online payments are not taken). Is there any way of editing the item.phtml file / emails so that the 0.00 is displayed as POA?

Comment: if my answer useful to you please accept it then I can give another answer